# Android Location NETWORK_PROVIDER && FusedLocation giving uncertain location

Tags: android, android-location

i am making application on tracking apps using NETWORK_PROVIDER & FusedLocation(No GPS) it's continuously getting location but when i am on road to navigat from one location to another location it giving some time previous location as you can check in below image in image i am moving to bottom to top then location 1,2,3,4,5,6 are perfect but **7th** location is previous then 8,9 are perfect location but **10th** is again previous and uncertain 11,12,13 are again on track but **14th** is again previous and uncertain.

[image]

i had used below code for getting location & i had change accuracy also accuracy high will not give me location till 4-5 hours in 4-5 hours singel location it's givning

```
public void start(){

    int resp =GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(mContext);
    if(resp == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
        locationClient = new LocationClient(mContext, this, this);
        locationClient.connect();
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Google Play Service Not Available " + resp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } 
    intent = new Intent(StaticData.BROADCAST_ACTION);
    filter = new IntentFilter(StaticData.BROADCAST_ACTION);
    receiver = new ResponseReceiver();
    mContext.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}

@SuppressWarnings({
        "static-access", "unused"
})
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    try {
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(1);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(1000*60);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000*60);
        locationManager = (LocationManager)mContext.getSystemService(mContext.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    } catch (Exception e1) {

    }

    try{
        Criteria crit = new Criteria();
        crit.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_MEDIUM);
        crit.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_MEDIUM);
        crit.setAltitudeRequired(false);
        crit.setBearingRequired(false);
        crit.setCostAllowed(true);
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(crit, true);
        locationClient.setMockMode(true);
    }catch (RuntimeException e) {
        AppLog.errorLog(TAG, e);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        AppLog.errorLog(TAG, e);
    }

    try {
        locationClient. requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, this);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, (1000*60), 10f, this);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        AppLog.errorLog(TAG, e);
    }
}
```

Now question is that how to overcome this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, relying on Network for geolocation are really uncertain. I advise you use GPS for accurate pinpointing of geolocation.

Comment: that's right but client are not ready to use GPS and i have to develop app on network as efficiency as possible

Comment: I see. The app should rely on ISPs. How about putting ranges on each point? Are they open about it or they really want the exact location of the user?

Comment: Not exact but if little accuracy is missing then it's fine but this is wrong i am going ahed and its giving me previous location

Comment: i think that some data are received late.

Comment: @Kerppag it should reture previous location but not prev to previous